# How do short-duration buffs work when used to buff rolls for longer-duration actions?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, skills, duration

How do buffs with short durations (let's say [*guidance*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/guidance/), which has a duration of up to 1 minute) work when used to buff rolls for longer-duration actions (such as a [heal](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/heal) check to treat disease, which takes 10 minutes)?

Does the buff work at all? Does it have to be cast right at the end before the check?

Comment: Is an answer like *Nobody knows* or *The game doesn't say* better than no answer at all?

Comment: I was sure it was already asked on this site. Or was it for another game from this family? Either way it would be great if someone happened to remember it and could link, I can't find it now.

Comment: Related: [Can temporary bonuses be used for magic item crafting checks?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/152191/can-temporary-bonuses-be-used-for-magic-item-crafting-checks)

Answer (score 2):

## It needs to last for the duration of the action, at least for skills.

If we look at the [description for skills](https://aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Skill%20Descriptions&Category=Skills), we can see the following line:

> Action: The type of action using the skill requires, or **the amount of time required for a check.**

When you make a skill check, you're making a single roll over that period of time. Not just at the start or the end. Therefore, the buff would need to last for the duration of the action required to make the skill check.

Comment: “Therefore, the buff would need to last for the duration of the action required to make the skill check,” [citation needed].

Comment: I agree that this is a valid interpretation, but needs to be officially supported to be a Stack answer.

Comment: [Crafter's Fortune](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/crafter-s-fortune/) *almost* supports this. I'm unsure if there is better evidence.

Comment: I agree this seems like a valid interpretation, but it is poorly supported. While i don't think it's worthless to point out, I am unsure I can in good faith mark this as accepted. I could easily see someone argue that a majority of the time is spent doing more mundane tasks, (prepping bandages, ensuring things are disinfected, etc.) and that a short 5 minute buff that covers the more crucial moments of the 10 minute check (diagnosing the disease, or determining how to treat it etc)

Comment: @Erudaki One could argue that those more mundane tasks are just as crucial (That lack of a +1 during the time meant that you didn't completely disinfect the equipment, the bandages were cut incorrectly, etc.). I do agree though, that it is very poorly supported in the rules, and it is perfectly reasonable to not accept this as the answer. I will also point out that having the buff cover the whole duration is also the safest method, as there is nothing that says when they make the check, so the GM could simply have you make it when the buff isn't present.

Comment: One could, but one could also argue that those mundane tasks are much easier. When talking about big bonuses, disinfecting bandages doesn't get harder and may be a trivial task to do perfectly, but diagnosing the disease does. (DC = Disease DC)

I do think that without clarification this does fall into GM discretion, and possibly the best answer may be it depends. I was hoping there was more to it than that RAW.